# Why build method isn't defined inside StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I'm currently learning Flutter. I tried to deep dive into Flutter Widget life-cycle, and I wonder why `StatefulWidget` are written like this :

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  // initState
  // setState
  // ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext build) {
    ...
  }
}
```

but not :

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  // initState
  // setState
  // ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext build) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I think the latter makes the source simple. But I don't know why they're using the former style ?

Comment: Official answer here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8794

Answer (score 17):

The reason why [**`StatefulWidget`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) uses a separate [**`State`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) class and not having **`build`** method inside its body is because all fields inside a [**`Widget`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget-class.html) are immutable, and this includes all its sub-classes.

You might have noticed that **`StatelessWidget`** has its **`build`** and other associated methods defined inside it, but that was possible due to the nature of **`StatelessWidget`** which is rendered completely using the provided info, and doesn't expect any future change in its **`State`**.

In the case of **`StatefulWidget`**, **`State`** information occasionally change (or expected to change) during the course of the app, thus this information isn't suitable for storage in a final field (**`build`**) to satisfy `Widget` class conditions (**all fields are immutable**). That's why **`State`** class is introduced. You just have to override the **`createState`** function to attach your defined **`State`** to your **`StatefulWidget`**, and let all that change happens in a separate class.

Comment: Could it also be because the state of a Stateful widget is not just the data element but also UI elements. Meaning, a stateful widget may show one text field and, upon a state change, it may show two text fields. So basically, upon a state change, the UI of a widget may also change and not just the data. 
Note: I really don't know if this is true. I am just looking for some more clarifiacation.

Answer (score 1):

In official file framework.dart they define reason as below.

- Putting a `Widget build(BuildContext context)` method on [State] rather
  than putting a `Widget build(BuildContext context, State state)` method
  on [StatefulWidget] gives developers more flexibility when subclassin [StatefulWidget].
- For example, [AnimatedWidget] is a subclass of [StatefulWidget] that
  introduces an abstract `Widget build(BuildContext context)` method for its
  subclasses to implement. If [StatefulWidget] already had a [build] method
  that took a [State] argument, [AnimatedWidget] would be forced to provide
  its [State] object to subclasses even though its [State] object is an
  internal implementation detail of [AnimatedWidget].
- Conceptually, [StatelessWidget] could also be implemented as a subclass of
  [StatefulWidget] in a similar manner. If the [build] method were on
  [StatefulWidget] rather than [State], that would not be possible anymore.
- Putting the [build] function on [State] rather than [StatefulWidget] also
  helps avoid a category of bugs related to closures implicitly capturing
  `this`. If you defined a closure in a [build] function on a
  [StatefulWidget], that closure would implicitly capture `this`, which is
  the current widget instance, and would have the (immutable) fields of that
  instance in scope:

```
class MyButton extends StatefulWidgetX {
   MyButton({super.key, required this.color});
   final Color color;
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context, State state) {
     return SpecialWidget(
      handler: () { print('color: $color'); },
       );
    }
  }
```

- Above code is invalid because suppose the parent builds `MyButton` with `color` being blue, the `$color` in the print function refers to blue, as expected. Now,
  suppose the parent rebuilds `MyButton` with green. The closure created by
  the first build still implicitly refers to the original widget and the
  `$color` still prints blue even through the widget has been updated to
  green; should that closure outlive its widget, it would print outdated
  information.
- In contrast, with the [build] function on the [State] object, closures
  created during [build] implicitly capture the [State] instance instead of
  the widget instance:

```
class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyButton({super.key, this.color = Colors.teal});

   final Color color;
   
 }
class MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return SpecialWidget(
       handler: () { print('color: ${widget.color}'); },
   );
 }
}
```

- Now when the parent rebuilds `MyButton` with green, the closure created by
  the first build still refers to [State] object, which is preserved across
  rebuilds, but the framework has updated that [State] object's [widget]
  property to refer to the new `MyButton` instance and `${widget.color}`
  prints green, as expected.

Comment: it would have been much simpler to take the state as an argument of the build function no ?

Comment: @vans if you use state as an argument then once the widget is rebuild it will take outdated information means it will not update the data it take previous data not update them.